# REST API - HTTP status for a partial response

Tags: api, http-status

I encounter the following case:
I have an API that allows me to retrieve a unique resource:

```
GET myapi/resource_id
```

If this resource does not exist, I return a `404` HTTP status code.

This API also allows to retrieve several resources via the same request:

```
GET myapi/resource_id1,resource_id2
```

Which HTTP status code should I send back if one of the two resources does not exist?

> 1. 200 with an explanation in the JSON in an error key
> 2. 206 which allows to be more explicit with an explanation in the JSON in an error key
> 3. 400 / 404 code but this is not fine because the API still returns one of the two information
> 4. another solution?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you returning 404 code or it is returning automatically.

Comment: While it may sound like a great idea to batch mutliple resources with a single request, you loose the property of making use of a cache for separate resources and eventually also get an unusable ETag value for that "batch-resource". HTTP is clearly not designed for such a strategy. The actual expensive thing to do is open a connection for each request, but as now plenty of clients support `Connection: keep-alive` sending mutliple requests via the same connection isn't an issue. The HTTP protocol guarantees that messages are received in the correct order here

Comment: I'm returning `404`code for a unique retrieve but I don't know which code I have to use for a multiple retrieve

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 options here.

- Send back 200 and don't even mention the missing resource.
- Send back 404 with an empty body.

The 206 is for range requests, the 400 is for malformed requests, so none of those apply here.